# TSQL function headache

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a tsql function which would return a table as a result of the execution of tsql queries. But I am always getting errors. Just wonder what's wrong with my code below.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetPostcodeBrowseByIds]
(
    @PostCodes varchar(1000),
    @SortBy int
)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
        postcode int,
        suburb varchar(100),
        [state] varchar(3)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @tmp table
    (
        postcode int,
        suburb varchar(100),
        [state] varchar(3)
    )
    declare @query varchar(1000)
    if @SortBy = 0
       begin
            set @query = N' select a.postcodeid as postcode,b.name as 
            suburb,a.state from postcode a inner join suburb b on
            a.postcodeid = b.postcodeid where a.postcodeid 
            in (select data from 
            dbo.fnSplit(''' + @PostCodes + ''','','')) order by a.postcodeid asc'
       end
    else
       begin
            set @query = N' select a.postcodeid as postcode,b.name as
            suburb,a.state from postcode a inner join suburb b on 
            a.postcodeid = b.postcodeid where a.postcodeid 
            in (select data from 
            dbo.fnSplit(''' + @PostCodes + ''','','')) order by b.Name asc'
       end
       insert into @result execute (@query)
    return
END
```

and other function that I had created to split the given postcodeids is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

`fnSplit` works find but the first function not.

This function is meant to be used to return the list of postcode, suburbnames and states based on the given postcodeids which is a delimited string. Example : 2001,2200,3400 and so on. and should be able to sorted based on postcode id itself or suburb name.

Any help would be appreciated much.

cheers

Comment: what is the problem????

Comment: We have no idea what this function is meant to do. Perhaps edit your "question" and add some explanation, and an actual question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the sort order, there's no need to resort to dynamic SQL<sup>1</sup>:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetPostcodeBrowseByIds]
(
    @PostCodes varchar(1000),
    @SortBy int
)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
        postcode int,
        suburb varchar(100),
        [state] varchar(3)
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @result (postcode,suburb,state)
    select a.postcodeid as postcode,b.name as suburb,a.state
    from postcode a
           inner join
         suburb b on a.postcodeid = b.postcodeid
    where a.postcodeid in (select data from dbo.fnSplit(@PostCodes,','))
    order by
        CASE WHEN @Sort = 0 THEN a.postcodeid END asc,
        CASE WHEN @Sort <> 0 THEN b.Name END asc

END
```

<sup>1</sup>Which, as you've no doubt now realised, you cannot use inside a `function` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to execute a procedure or code from a function.

This fails:

```
insert into @result execute (@query)
```

I should add that the @tmp table is not used in your code